# Stacked Conditional Random Field (CRF) implementation

Tags: python, natural-language, software, conditional-random-field

I am looking for a library that can train a stacked conditional random field (CRF). I plan to use it for natural language processing purposes. Ideally, Python interface, works on Linux, and multi-threaded.

---

Example of stacked CRF: Cohen, William W., and Vitor R. Carvalho. "Stacked Sequential Learning." CRF 1: 1-17. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3232507054622963641&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/postscript/ijcai-2005-stack.pdf

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any library so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: By "stacked" do you mean for example "character-level + token-level"?

Comment: @filannim that could be one example where the window size is variable, but even basic stacking would be interesting too :) I have added a figure in the question.